# string to integer and formating code in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, int

I need to read from a file the number of times a letter v is mentioned. I actually know for a fact that if 'v' is in that sentence it will be the first thing to show up. The way I have it set up it goes and counts string by string and that is how it writes it, but I wan to just have one sentence mentioning the number of times 'v' is mentioned in the whole file.

```
f = open("triangle.txt", 'r')      #opens the given name file to read input
fw = open("convert.txt",'w')      #opens the given name file to write in

for line in f:
    data = line.strip().split(" ")
    vertices=0
    vertices =(str(data.count('v')))
    fw.write("Number of vertices = " + vertices +'\n')

f.close()
fw.close()
```

I tried

```
vertices += int((str(data.count('v'))))
```

yet that keeps giving me an error message that I can't convert string to integer. 
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you want one sentence that mentions number of times 'v' is mentioned, simply write this line

```
fw.write("Number of vertices = " + vertices +'\n')
```

out of for loop. secondly,

```
data.count('v')
```

will give you an int value as output, so you don't have to first convert it to string and then back to integer. here's the amended code;

```
f = open("triangle.txt", 'r')      #opens the given name file to read input
fw = open("convert.txt",'w')      #opens the given name file to write in
vertices=0
for line in f:
    data = line.strip().split(" ")
    vertices += ((data.count('v')))
fw.write("Number of vertices = " + str(vertices) +'\n')

f.close()
fw.close()
```

Also, your code only counts 'v', if it is mentioned as an individual word in the sentence. to count the total number of times 'v' occurred, use what @bad_keypoints suggested.

Comment: right I was getting hung up on adding it that I didn't recall that the count will give me an integer back. The problem was with the write I was writing line by line and not the total. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to know the number of times `v` was mentioned in the file, why don't you simple do this:

```
with open('file.dat', 'r+') as f:
    v_count = f.read().count('v')
```

Comment: So using this code it does count the # of v's the way I was expecting, however when I try to count another letter at the same time it only returns the top line for instance
    with open('file.dat', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f: 
            f_count = f.read().count('f')
            v_count = f.read().count('v')
will only give me the number of times 'f' was counted and not 'v' as well

Comment: @Luis That's not black magic. That's how `read` works. It reads the whole file all at once. You can put the read content into another variable, and then do the counting for all the other strings on that.